# Java- Does hibernate have support of auditing mode and history support?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Is it possible for me to add the history support and auditing mode in  hibernate ORM.
If yes, is it supported by default or I should use custom annotations?
I read several documentations and couldn't figure it out. Please provide me detailed answer.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/ Follow this tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Hibernate Envers
http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/